# Google Map API v3 Search Places Starting From My Location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I need to implement a search for all closes pharmacies starting from my location, the code i wrote sometimes works and sometimes don't, The search always works but what always work is pinning my location and setting it as a starting point in the search.

Sometime when i enter the page for the fist everything works, then after a refresh of the page the lat and long takes the default values that i have set and not My Location, when this happens i open the debug on chrome and trace some lines and suddenly everything works fine, i am not sure what really happens here but hopefully someone could help me cause i am stuck.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    var infowindow;
    var lat = 26.304295; //29.331647;
    var lng = 50.155233; //48.074473;

    function success(position) {

    };

    function error(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }

    var request = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
                lat = pos.coords.latitude;
                lng = pos.coords.longitude;

                $("#Lat").val(lat);
                $("#Lng").val(lng);
            }, function (error) {
                // ...
            }, { timeout: 10000 });
        }
    });

    $.when(request).done(function () {

        function initialize() {

            if ($("#Lat").val() != "")
                lat = $("#Lat").val();

            if ($("#Lng").val() != "")
                lng = $("#Lng").val();

            var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                center: pyrmont,
                zoom: 14
            });

            var request = {
                location: pyrmont,
                radius: 3000,
                types: ['pharmacy']
            };
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

            var myloc = new google.maps.Marker({
                clickable: false,
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mobile/mobileimgs2.png',
                                                        new google.maps.Size(22, 22),
                                                        new google.maps.Point(0, 18),
                                                        new google.maps.Point(11, 11)),
                shadow: null,
                zIndex: 999,
                map: map
            });

            var me = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            myloc.setPosition(me);
        }

        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        function createMarker(place) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    });

</script>
```

Here is my html code:

```
 <div id="map-canvas">
</div>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Lat" Value="" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Lng" Value="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what was the issue here. To be able to get your location you will have to have a fully initialized map first and that is why whenever i tried to get my location it always executes second whatever i do. To solve this problem call get my location function then initialize the map, the map will be initialized first then my location function will be called, after that just point the new long and lat into the map and do you search for places and that is that.

Here is how the code turned out:

```
   <script>
    var map;
    var infowindow;
    var pyrmont;
    var lat = 29.331647;
    var lng = 48.074473;

    function initialize() {

        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: pyrmont,
            zoom: 14
        });
    }

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(place.name);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }

    //Get current location and re-initialize the map to it
    //Search starting from your location
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    function success(pos) {
        var crd = pos.coords;

        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(crd.latitude, crd.longitude);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: pyrmont,
            zoom: 14
        });

        var request = {
            location: pyrmont,
            radius: 3000,
            types: ['pharmacy']
        };
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

        var myloc = new google.maps.Marker({
            clickable: false,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mobile/mobileimgs2.png',
                                                        new google.maps.Size(22, 22),
                                                        new google.maps.Point(0, 18),
                                                        new google.maps.Point(11, 11)),
            shadow: null,
            zIndex: 999,
            map: map
        });

        var me = new google.maps.LatLng(crd.latitude, crd.longitude);
        myloc.setPosition(me);
    };

    function error(err) {
        console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
    };
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //Call get my location
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

    //Initialize the map
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```